# How can I pass more than one enum to a method that receives only one?

Tags: c#, parameters, enums, parameter-passing

I'm wondering if the following is possible:

The method `Regex.Match` can receive an enum, so I can specify:

```
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhiteSpace
RegexOptions.Multiline
```

**What if I need to specify more than just one?** (eg. I want my regex to be `Multiline` and I want it to ignore the pattern whitespace).

**Could I use `|` operator like in C/C++?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to annotate it with [`[Flags]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) attribute and use [`|`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-flags) operator to combine them.

In the case you mentioned, you can do that because [`RegexOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) enum is annotated with it.

---

### More References:

[A helpful way to use the FlagsAttribute with enumerations](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EnumsFlagsAttribute.aspx)

#### Example Snippet from above CodeProject article:

Definition:

```
[FlagsAttribute]
public enum NewsCategory : int 
{
    TopHeadlines =1,
    Sports=2,
    Business=4,
    Financial=8,
    World=16,
    Entertainment=32,
    Technical=64,
    Politics=128,
    Health=256,
    National=512
}
```

Use:

```
mon.ContentCategories = NewsCategory.Business | 
                        NewsCategory.Entertainment | 
                        NewsCategory.Politics;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since it is an Enum with a Flags Attribute, you can use:

```
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhiteSpace | RegexOptions.Multiline
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a [`Flags` enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) you need to to a bitwise `OR`:

```
var combine = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhiteSpace | RegexOptions.Multiline;
myFunction(combine);
```

If this is not such an enum, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx for details.

Don't use `&`, use `|` (you want to do a bit-wise Boolean OR).

Answer (score 0):

Just to enhance the answers a bit, the Flags attribute is not a requirement. Every enum value can be combined with the bitwise | operator. The Flags attribute only makes the enum a bit more readable when converted into a string (eg. instead of seeing a number with the bitwise result as a number, you see the selected flags combined).

To test if a condition is set you normally would use a bitwise &. This will also work without the Flags attribute.

In the MSDN documentation for this attribute there is an example of two enums, one with and the other without it: [FlaggsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx).